BizTalk Server 2020 - Why Configuration To Enable REST APIs Fails?
I'm trying to enable the REST APIs feature using the BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard as described here. However, it won't display any content in the REST APIs tab. I get the following error.

I know we can get Microsoft.Web.Administration from Nuget etc, but how to address this at the server level where there's no Visual Studio installed? This is an existing BizTalk Server in operation for many months, since the upgrade to 2020 (ie, not new).

Was it an in-place upgrade, or a new build?

@Dijkgraaf - update was done a long time ago. It was a new build in Azure. Recently came across the documentation about REST API capabilities introduced in BTS2020, so I was trying to enable it in a non production server.

Try to download the missing dll from your visual studio dev env and copy the dll from this one ang GAC it directly to the BizTalk Server (or by copying it in the same folder where you have BizTalk admin console)
